# Meaning of a limit-related statement

Tags: calculus, limits

I saw this definition in one of the computer science book but I am unable to recall the theorem name. Can someone please provide the reference?

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = c > 0$$ means there is some $n_{0}$ beyond which the ratio is always between $\frac{1}{2}c$ and $2c$.

Comment: "There is some no beyond"?

Comment: Some number n0 it is n0 not no

Comment: Book name: algorithm design by Jon Kleinberg

Answer (score 0):

What is actually true
(from the definition of limit)
is that
$ \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=c>0$
means that
for any
$a > 0$ and $b > 0$
there is an
$N(a,b)$
such that
for all $n > N(a, b)$
$c-a < \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} < c+b$.

For your case,
let $a = c/2$
and $b = c$.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please provide some reference books or url?

Comment: It's the *definition* of the existence of the limit of a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of a limit of a sequence of real numbers as $n \to \infty$ is as follows:

> $a_n \to L$ as $n \to \infty$ iff $\forall \epsilon > 0 \; \exists \; N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n \ge N \; \left| a_n - L \right| < \epsilon$

Intuitively this means that some sequence $a_n$ converges to a point $L$ if and only if for any bound one can come up with, one can find a specific term in the sequence where every term afterwards is also bounded by said bound.

Note that by bound above I mean that $\left| a_n - L \right|$ is bounded.

Now for your problem, given that the sequence converges, we know that any bound we want can be obtained for all terms after some $n_0^{th}$ term. So we can pick our bound to be $c/2$ so that we know
$$
\exists \; n_0 \in \mathbb{N} \; s.t. \; \left| \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} - c \right| < \frac{c}{2}
$$
again working out the absolute values we get
$$
\frac{c}{2} < \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} < \frac{3c}{2} \; \forall n \ge n_0
$$

Now this isn't exactly the bounds that you specified, theyre actually better bounds. Since $c > 0$ we have that
$$
\frac{3c}{2} < \frac{4c}{2} = 2c
$$
so that indeed we have
$$
\frac{c}{2} < \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} < 2c \; \forall n \ge n_0
$$

Hope this helps. If you're confused on any part let me know.

EDIT: I see you want a reference for the above post, one for this answer would be [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence)